# Download archived mercurial repositories from bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

BitBucket dropped support for mercurial. But the repositories that were not manually deleted can still be found with a name like `something_123456_hg` when I try to add repositories in a project. But they are not selectable. Neither I can find them by searching the repositories or adding the name in the correct position in the url.

tried to clone them with `hg clone` which ended up to 403 ( the credentials were correct) .

I am really curious if there is a way to download those repositories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Softwareheritage](https://www.softwareheritage.org/) has archived all the **public** repos [here](https://bitbucket-archive.softwareheritage.org/projects), if you can't get at them any other way.